# Using Debug-Only suffix for referenced C++ DLLs in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010

In previous versions of Visual Studio (from VC6 up to VS2008), we have had the convention of putting a "D" at the end of the names of debug-build DLLs, as is done for MFC and the CRT libraries.  So, for example, if the release-build DLLs are "foo.dll", "bar.dll", and "baz.dll", the debug-build names are "fooD.dll", "barD.dll", and "bazD.dll".  This prevents us from accidentally mixing release and debug DLLs.

However, we are having trouble doing this with the new C++ build system in VS2010.  It worked with the dependency-based system in older releases, but now project references are apparently based upon the target DLL name, so it seems that they have to be the same for both Debug and Release builds.

The obvious solution is to just abandon the debug-build suffix, but we'd prefer to keep it if possible.  Is anyone else doing this, and have they figured out how to make it work with VS2010?

---

BTW, I ran across [Using Visual Studio project properties effectively for multiple projects and configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502530/using-visual-studio-project-properties-effectivly-for-multiple-projects-and-confi).  I'll have to review it with other team members to determine whether it might solve our problem.

Comment: Hi, sorry to update this old question but did you find an answer for your question? I just ran into the same issue with VS2012.

Comment: I don't think we found an easy solution. We had a tool that controls the build, and I think we hacked that up to get it to generate different projects/solutions for Debug vs. Release. (It was a couple of years ago, so my memory is hazy and I no longer work at that company.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried editing the project options in `Linker > General > Output File`, `Linker > Advanced > Import Library` and `Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies` for the project linking the lib. I hope that should fix it (haven't tested yet, it's still building)