# Accessing the runtime library property in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing the runtime library property in visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800555/accessing-the-runtime-library-property-in-visual-studio-2010)

This is basically a follow up question to: Using Visual Studio project properties effectivly for multiple projects and configurations

Our library's target name is currently in this format: $(ProjectName)-$(PlatformToolset)-$(PlatformShortName)-$(Configuration) We'd like to add information about the runtime library used by the project to the target name, I tried adding $(RuntimeLibrary), but that doesn't seem to be set. Is there any other way to get the runtime library at the time the target name is resolved?

Thanks!