# Visual Studio UserMacros (and general property sheet) Syntax?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, programming-languages, propertysheet

I've scoured around and haven't been able to find any kind of a decent reference guide on Visual Studio property sheets. Most of what you can do with them cannot be done through the UI, so I've got to think there is a reference guide somewhere that can be useful in understanding the available fields, syntax, etc.

Lunicon's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502530/using-visual-studio-project-properties-effectively-for-multiple-projects-and-con) was really useful, but I'd really like to know where the information on what could be done in property sheets came from. I'm hoping it was not a lot of trial and error. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a decent reference guide at all, but I did notice that there is a schema for the property sheet defined here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak4435es(v=vs.80).aspx