# User macro having different values depending on configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, projects-and-solutions

In Visual C++ 2012, I want to have a user-defined macro (the ones used in project property sheets) whose value can be defined differently for each configuration.

I have created user macros [with help of this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#bkmkToCreatePropertySheet), but changing its value for a specific configuration changes it for all configurations.

Is there a way to have its value defined differently at each configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer in this post: [Using Visual Studio project properties effectively for multiple projects and configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502530/using-visual-studio-project-properties-effectively-for-multiple-projects-and-con)

In the newly created `.props` file, replace the first `PropertyGroup` with the following

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
    <MilVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug-ConfigA'">Value1</MilVersion>
    <MilVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug-ConfigB'">Value2</MilVersion>
    <MilVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release-ConfigA'">Value1</MilVersion>
    <MilVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release-ConfigB'">Value2</MilVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In this code, the user macro `$(MilVersion)` will be `Value1` in configurations `(Debug|Release)-ConfigA`, and `Value2` in configurations `(Debug|Release)-ConfigB`.